# What edition of DB is best?

Tags: database, primavera

If a user wishes to run Primavera on SE database instead of EE, what are the pros and cons he is looking at?

Answer (score 0):

As a first recommendation, I would say that it does not matter, go with the SE if price is an issue and you don't have an EE instance already.

SE size is limited to 64GB vs 2 TB for EE.  But I have not seen a P6 database even as large as 64 GB.

Database mirroring in SE is limited to single thread asynchronous.  But will you require that?

Remember, unless you are running a super-critical, high-activity system, most databases will do the job well enough.  P6 and PCM do not demand that much from a database from what I have seen.  The bottlenecks usually arise from the desktop client and/or web application servers.

Cheers,
Daniel